# Windows 7 installer: Select CD-ROM boot type

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, mac, boot

I am attempting to install Windows 7 **over** Elementary OS (Ubuntu) on a machine that originally ran OS X. When I attempt to boot to the installer, I get the following message:

```
  .2
Select CD-ROM boot type:
```

I know the CD is good, but it gets stuck here every time.

This is what I have done to the machine (Mac Pro 1,1 from 2006) since I bought it:

- Swapped the GPU with an old Nvidia 8800 GTX
- Installed Elementary OS **over** OS X because the GPU was not supported on OS X.
- Wiped and reformatted the hard drive, then reinstalled Elementary OS.
- Attempted to boot from the Windows 7 install CD.

Those should be all of the major factors, so what do I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought was that grub might be interfering. Try disabling the hard drive in the bios (or remove the drive physically) and see if the cd will boot then.

If that works you can try cleaning the hard drive with a GParted Live CD or another like it.

Option 2: You can try making a bootable USB Stick and see if that will boot for you to install Win7.

Comment: How would I go about disabling the hard drive with the Mac EFI system (no BIOS)?

Comment: Okay, it's working now. What I did was wipe the entire drive and setup a new partition table, so there was nothing to boot but the CD. Then the installer started up without a hitch and let me install completely fresh.

Comment: Had a feeling it had something to do with that. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to preserve your existing mac partition AND you get the 'Select CD-ROM Boot Type' on your older mac, then you have 2 possibilities:

1. use the 32bit version
2. download the special mac 64bit version from here:
   http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.2/release/